# どうして rails では timestamp ではなく datetime を created_at などに利用するのですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, rails-activerecord

Rails の ActiveRecord では、 migration において `t.timestamps` で導入される `created_at` や `updated_at` のカラムについて、少なくとも MySQL においては、 datetime 型を DB 上に作成します。

`datetime` 型は、いうなればその時刻をタイムゾーンなしで文字列で DB 上に保存しているのに近く、そのデータが動作していた AP(Rails) サーバーがどのタイムゾーンで動いていたのかの情報がない限り、そのデータは正しく取扱えなくなってしまいます。

database に時刻を保存するのならば、なので、 `timestamp` 型を用いた方が良さそうな気がするのですが、 Rails ではそのような設計にはなっていないです。

#### 質問

- なぜ、 rails では `created_at` や `updated_at` に `timestamp` ではなく `datetime` を利用するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

railsの仕様については分からないので申し訳ありませんが、私個人としてはMySQLで日時を記録するためにはdatetime型が適しているのではないかと考えます。

[MySQLのDATETIME型とTIMESTAMP型の違いを検証してみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ykawakami/items/2449a24e3b82ff0cbab6)

理由は、この記事にもある通り、timestamp型ではいわゆる2038年問題を潜在的に含んでしまうからです。
今後のバージョンアップで対応される可能性はありますが、システムに組み込もうとした場合、一定のリスクとも考えられるのではないでしょうか。